# "'RCTAppDelegate.h' not found" after running "Clean Build Folder" in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-config

I added an iOS target for stage build for my react-native project using XCode and updated the pre build script

`cp "${PROJECT_DIR}/../.env.staging" "${PROJECT_DIR}/../.env"`

to use multiple environments. It works fine and the project builds, however if I run "Clean Build Folder" from XCode and try to run the scheme for stage it gives this error.

`'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found`

I am using XCode 14.2 and react native 0.71.6

I have tried recreating my targets but got similar results.
It still works with the original scheme/target even after cleaning the build folder.